# JavaScript error on Photoshop CS6 (random image creator)

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am currently using this script, but Photoshop CS6 shows this error when running
[error image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoMuj.jpg)

What edits would this script need to run on Photoshop CS6?
Also what would I need to change to save the images as JPEGS and not PNGS

Thank you

```html
function Visible() {
  var Grps = app.activeDocument.layerSets; // loops through all groups
  for(var i = 0; i < Grps.length; i++){
    var tmp = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers.length;
    app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].visible=true;
    var groupChildArr = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers;
    var randLays = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp);
    groupChildArr[randLays].visible = true;
    Save();
  }
  Revert();
}

function Save() {
  var outFolder = app.activeDocument; // psd name
  var outPath = outFolder.path;
  var fName = "PNG";   // define folder name
  var f = new Folder(outPath + "/" + fName);
  if ( ! f.exists ) {
    f.create()
  }
  var saveFile = new File(outPath + "/" + fName +"/" + "Pattern_" +  num + ".png");
  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
  app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}

function Revert(){
  var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
  var desc300 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref163 = new ActionReference();
  var idSnpS = charIDToTypeID( "SnpS" );
  ref163.putName( idSnpS, "test.psd" );
  desc300.putReference( idnull, ref163 );
  executeAction( idslct, desc300, DialogModes.NO );
}

var count = prompt("How many patterns you want","");
for (var x=0 ; x<count;x++){
  var num = x+1;
  Visible();
}
```

Comment: That error seems to have absolutely nothing to do with this code.

Comment: Thank you for the response! do you know how I could change the save settings to JPEG? I tried changing all the portions that say PNG into JPEG but get another error saying:
Error 2: JpegSaveOptions is undefined.
Line:25
-> app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, JpegSaveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);

im a complete noob to code as well as stack overflow...thank you @tadman

Answer (score 0):

PNG doesn't have the same options as JPEG so doing a copy and replace isn't going to help you.

```
// png file options
pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);

// jpg file options
var jpgFile = new File(saveFile);
jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
jpgSaveOptions.quality = 12; // or whatever jpeg quality you want. 12 is max
app.activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

The revert function is causing your error. Change it to:

```
function Revert()
{
  var idRvrt = charIDToTypeID( "Rvrt" );
  executeAction( idRvrt, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
}
```